# How to implement memory simulation in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

Basically I need to have two lists, one of which keeps the list of empty memory holes by storing the starting point and the size of each hole. The other one, keeps information about various processes (while there is no actual process data, rather just the id and starting location and size).

So, I understand that I will need to have two structs, each of which defines the "hole" and the "process". I will need to have two lists to store these objects.

What I don't understand, is how to "initialize memory". For example, if the user wants to initialize(5000 bytes), what should the initialize method do in respect to the two lists?

Comment: This has already been done in libc with stuff like `malloc()`, `free()`, etc. Take a look at how it implements memory allocation, because I know there is some sort of data structure in use that manages "chunks" of memory that are allocated. However, I believe this may tie in more to how virtual memory is done, which is closer to an operating-system level function.

Comment: The first list sounds like a *free list*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list

Comment: @Michael This sounds like homework, so "the stdlib already has it" isn't an option.

Comment: @Inerdia So should we not encourage them to learn on their own?

Comment: @antonpug: You should use the homework tag if this is in fact a uni assignment.

Comment: Taking a C class as an elective, without prior knowledge of C or data structures is a rather stupid idea, I agree.

Comment: @Michael: I replied before your edit came through, apparently.

Comment: @antonpug: Well, I wouldn't say it's unfeasible to invent free lists from scratch with the guidance. (That said it's really not a beginner-level problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just empty the process list (since no memory is allocated) and create a single hole from address 0 to address 4999 (since those addresses are empty).

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a regular memory manager with malloc() and free() equivalents and extend it to support extra control data (e.g. your process IDs). Or allocate a large block of memory, carve it up in smaller per-process pieces and implement memory management inside of those pieces. Take a look, for example, at [Doug Lea's memory allocator](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html).

See also [Wikipedia on Memory Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) in general. Follow links.